# Can't Change WooCommerce Default Language to Spanish (Mexico)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, localization, e-commerce

Going a bit mad here on how complicated they have managed to make changing the language in WooCommerce.

My site is in Spanish (Mexico), interface admin is in Spanish.I have also managed to set Storefront (theme) in Spanish (Mexico).

I then proceeded to visit this URL to download the po file for WooCommerce:

https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce

Download the latest stable version as: wp-plugins-woocommerce-stable-es-mx.po

I tried placing this file inside:

wp-content/languages/woocommerce
wp-content/languages/plugins
wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce

And it just does not show up on Spanish.

I renamed the file to woocommerce-es_MX.po and tried in these three directories with no luck.

I have search all over the place but everyone has different suggestions from questions that are a bit dated, so I'm wondering if something has changed.

Incredibly frustrated....thanks much in advance.

Comment: Oh god...I just tried to "Update Translations" and now it just magically works...so frustrating...  So if this happens to anyone, you don't need to download anything...just set your language in wordpress, go to the Updates section and at the bottom you will see language updates. Update those files and the WooCommerce files will be downloaded for you...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c854wHSqGLNBnQ55QIMbu2GL4d8Em9-i

Answer (score 1):

Oh god...I just tried to "Update Translations" and now it just magically works...so frustrating...

So if this happens to anyone, you don't need to download anything...just set your language in wordpress under **General**, go to the **Updates** section and at the bottom you will see language updates. Update those files and the WooCommerce language files will be downloaded for you - nothing else to do!

[Screenshot of Upgraded Language Files in Spanish](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1c854wHSqGLNBnQ55QIMbu2GL4d8Em9-i)

Comment: The reason your manual method didn't work is that WordPress reads .mo files. Not .po files. The .po files are editable sources from which the .mo files are compiled.

Comment: Thanks for this, I just saw the option for downloading the .mo files as well, will pay more attention next time for sure!